# Can't set PHP session via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

Last 4 hours passed with my effort to make a basic setting of a PHP session.

Here's what I have,

I have index.html that has a javascript which contains an `on click function` as;

```
$("a.yes").on('click', function() {

    $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.example.com/blabla/php/register.php",
            data: "test=" + "test2"

        })
          .done(function(data){

        alert($(data).filter(".meme").text());
        })
        .fail(function() {

            alert( "Error" );

        });
});
```

My AJAX Post handler file is (aka register.php);

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
include "../../includes/connect.php";

if ($_POST['test']){
    $_SESSION['mysession'] = $_POST['test']
?>
<span class='meme'><?=$_SESSION['mysession']?></span>
<?php

}
?>
```

It alerts my posted value as `test2` but not setting the session when I check it afterwards. But if it is not setting the session how it alerts `test2`?

What could be wrong?
PS: I tried without `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` but result is the same. I need it anyway.

**UPDATE:** It seems sessions for www and non www version are different... There is no problem when they are both www or non www. Solved.

Comment: are you having a cross domain request?

Comment: Yes. But I tried without it also.

Comment: then you should know `jsonp` is the way to go.

Comment: Like I said, I tried it without CORS, I use the same logic another place in my website, but this one, just not works.

Comment: You're setting the session in a remote page and expecting the session to be available in the local page immediately? Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: I tried with same domain, too. Actually this code is running at same domain right now. Why I use CORS is, I'll implement it in Phonegap later.

Comment: OK - here's the thing: a session started in a remote page will not be available in the local page until the local page is reloaded (the session is server-side). The session is likely being started in the remote page but the local page has no awareness of the session because no server-side code has been run in the local page after the AJAX request.

Comment: Tried it right now, with both files are on the same domain in server. With replacing the URL to a local file. But it's just the same...

Comment: How is the session started on the page with the AJAX?  If you are using sessions, and then go to a page with no session start command, then the session will be interrupted.

Comment: If the page is ending in .html, then how is it interacting with the php interpreter?  How would PHP commands for Session be applied on that page?

Comment: Where are you checking if the session is set?